# Remove polygons that do not fall completely inside overlay layer within the clip function

Tags: qgis, polygon, clip

I have two polygons: 1) successfulheights and 2) clipArea. I have used the clip function to remove the unwanted successfulheights. Though, there are features that have been clipped in half and those are now invalid for my project. Is there a parameter to set, "if a feature does not completely lay within the overlay layer, remove it"?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is better to use the [Extract by location](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorselection.html#extract-by-location) tool instead of the [Clip](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectoroverlay.html#clip) tool to extract only those polygons that fall completely within the boundary polygon. `Extract by location` has the option `are within` which does what you want.

Input:

[image]

Extract by location:

[image]

Output:

[image]

Comment: That's perfect! Thanks for sharing!